# Can I downloading data from a meteor.com deployed app

Tags: meteor

I've recently deployed an app to meteor.com, and was wondering if its possible to download the mongodb database for the app.  I could not find any reference to data access in the Meteor documentation.

At some point I might want to deploy to another hosting site, and want to be able to take my data with me.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024888/is-there-a-simple-way-to-export-the-data-from-a-meteor-deployed-app

Answer (score 0):

I believe either of the following options would work for you:

[How do I use an existing MongoDB in a Meteor project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588038/how-to-use-the-existing-mongodb-in-a-meteor-project)

[Restore a mongodb in meteor production server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687404/restore-a-mongodb-in-meteor-production-server)